# ¿Cómo saber el tipo genérico de una colección en Java?

Tags: java, gson, collection

Estoy tratando de hacer unos métodos que sirvan para hacer conversiones de una cadena `Json` a un tipo de dato que herede `Collection` el problema es cuando se necesita el tipo de dato `Genérico` ya que para hacer la conversión como la estoy definiendo necesito saber de qué tipo es y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

Adjunto el código del método:

```
public Collection convertirJsonAColeccion(String json, Collection coleccion) throws Exception{
        if(json == null || json.equals("")){ // Se valida que no esté vacía la cadena, sí lo está lanza la excepción.
            throw new Exception("La cadena está vacía");
        }

        Type tipoColeccion = new TypeToken<Collection>(){}.getType(); // Sé que aquí debe definir el tipo de dato generico de la colección, pero como no es uno en especifico no sé como acomodarlo
        Gson gson = crearGson();
        coleccion = gson.fromJson(json, tipoColeccion);
        return coleccion;
```

Así lo pruebo:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.add(2);
ints.add(3);
String json = parametro.convertirColeccionAJson(ints);
System.out.println(json);

List<Integer> ints2 = new ArrayList();
ints2 = (List<Integer>) parametro.convertirJsonAColeccion(json, ints2);
for(Integer intt : ints2) {
   System.out.println(intt);
}
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme, es complicado de explicar así que sí no es entendible trataré de aclararlo mejor.

---

ACTUALIZACIÓN

La clase:

```
public class ParametrosJson<T> {

....

// Metodo para convertir una cadena json a una coleccion.
    public Collection<T> convertirJsonAColeccion(String json) throws Exception{
        if(json == null || json.equals("")){ // Se valida que no esté vacía la cadena, sí lo está lanza la excepción.
            throw new Exception("La cadena está vacía");
        }
        Type tipoColeccion = new TypeToken<Collection<T>>(){}.getType(); // Obtien el tipo de coleccion teniendo en cuenta los generics
        // En la linea anterior es donde está el error ya que se debe definir el generic del collection algo así: Collection<Integer> entonces tomaría bien el tipo de dato 
        Gson gson = crearGson();
        return gson.fromJson(json, tipoColeccion);
        /* Nota: Al llamar el metodo se debe castear con el tipo de coleccion en el que se está guardando.
        * Ejemplo:
        * List<?> lista = new ArrayList();
        * lista = (List<?>) convertirJsonAObjeto(json, lista); */
    }
}
```

Como la llamo en el main para ejecutarla:

```
List<Integer> ints2 = new ArrayList();
ParametrosJson<Integer> parametro2 = new ParametrosJson<Integer>();
ints2 = (List<Integer>) parametro2.convertirJsonAColeccion(json);
for(Integer intt : ints2) {
    System.out.println(intt);
}
```

Comment: Pero si haces un casting a `(List<Integer>)` entonces ya sabes que la colección es de tipo Integer `TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>`

Comment: Ya, pero ^TypeToken<Collection>()}` no le estoy definiendo el tipo generico, y por alguna razón me lo convierte en un double

Comment: Es un comportamiento por defecto de Gson, trata los números como double.

Comment: Entonces qué debería hacer?

Comment: Según lo que entiendo lo que quieres  es un método que se capaz de deserealizar cualquier tipo de colección?

Comment: Sí y que no haya problemas por el tipo generico que justamente lo que me está pasando

Comment: Ya probaste usando `instanceOf`?

Comment: @RuslanLópez usando el instanceOf tendría preguntar por cada instancia posible que pueda tomar, y no sería tan buena idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar genéricos hay que usar el método `getParameterized()` de la clase `TypeToken` y en la llamada de la función pasarle el tipo:

```
class ParametrosJson<T> {

// Metodo para convertir una cadena json a una coleccion.
    public Collection<T> convertirJsonAColeccion(String json,Class<T> clase) throws Exception{
        if(json == null || json.equals("")){ // Se valida que no esté vacía la cadena, sí lo está lanza la excepción.
            throw new Exception("La cadena está vacía");
        }

        Type tipoColeccion = TypeToken.getParameterized(Collection.class, clase).getType();// Obtien el tipo de coleccion teniendo en cuenta los generics
        // En la linea anterior es donde está el error ya que se debe definir el generic del collection algo así: Collection<Integer> entonces tomaría bien el tipo de dato 
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(json, tipoColeccion);
        /* Nota: Al llamar el metodo se debe castear con el tipo de coleccion en el que se está guardando.
        * Ejemplo:
        * List<?> lista = new ArrayList();
        * lista = (List<?>) convertirJsonAObjeto(json, lista); */
    }
}
```

LLamada:

```
ints2 = (List<Integer>) parametro2.convertirJsonAColeccion(json,Integer.class);
```

Comment: Sería la única forma? Planeaba no involucrar cambios en la clase solamente centrarme en el método

Comment: Según la documentación de Gson para deserealizar hay que espeficiar el tipo de dato. https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#collections-limitations

Comment: Por eso pensé en trabajar con genéricos así se mantiene un solo código para convertir cualquier tipo de datos.

Comment: El problema es que ordenaron centrarme solamente en el metodo sin manipular la clase

Comment: Entiendo. Se puede modificar el método pero siempre hay que pasarle alguna bandera para indicarle el tipo de dato.

Comment: Lo intenté, pero no me funciona

Comment: Qué problema tienes?

Comment: Pues al parecer no toma en cuenta el generic, no sé por qué, traté de acomodarlo a como ya lo venía manejando, ya edito la pregunta y te muestro

Comment: Listo, así fue como lo implementé

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta. Agregué la primera implementación que había hecho sin genéricos. Investigaré el por qué no funcionó con genéricos.

Comment: Gracias, igual preferiría manejarlo con genéricos, también voy a revisar a ver que sucede